# Automatically Transforming C code

Tags: c, regex, visual-studio

Let's suppose I have this simple code:

```
void xorFunction (unsigned char output[], unsigned char a[], unsigned char b[], size_t length)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        output[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char input[16] = { ... };
    unsigned char mask[16] = { ... };
    unsigned char output[16];

    xorFunction(output, input, mask, 16);
    xorFunction(mask, output, input, 16);
    xorFunction(input, mask, output, 16);

    return 0;
}
```

and that suddenly, I want to get rid of the `xorFunction` so I decide to write `for(i = 0; i < length; i++) ...` instead of `xorFunction(...);`

How can I do it with the find and replace tool of my text editor?

It could look like something like this:

```
Find: xorFunction(a, b, c, d);

Replace with: for(unsigned int i = 0; i < d; i++) a[i] = b[i] ^ c[i];
with a, b, c and d parameters of xorFunction.
```

How can `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` be variables handled by the find and replace tool? I suppose that regex would be useful in this case but I don't know how.

Comment: Find `xorFunction\s*\(\s*([^,]*?)\s*,\s*([^,]*?)\s*,\s*([^,]*?)\s*,\s*([^)]*?)\s*\)\s*;` Replace with whatever you want. A,B,C,D are in groups 1,2,3,4 respectively.

Comment: The answer will depend on which editor is your text editor. With simple calls like those shown, it isn't very hard. If you have calls like `xorFunction(someFunc(arg1, arg2), otherFunc(arg3, arg4), mask_generator(i), 16)`, then the regex needed to isolate the arguments to `xorFunction` become profoundly tricky. (Note that the nested commas in my example break the suggested regex in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181060/variables-in-regular-expressions#comment89344637_51181060). It likely works for the shown code; I may be raising an irrelevant issue. But you need to know.)

Comment: @sln I tried your code but it doesn't seem to work. Jonathan Leffler, I am under Visual Studio and my calls are of the kind shown, no problem about that

Comment: You need an MSVS user — that isn't me.  But if your calls are as simple as shown, something along the general lines of @sin's regex will work.  The `\s` (white space) and `*?` (non-greedy match) notations have the potential to be problematic (misunderstood).

Comment: How about using `gcc -E`? Replace your `xorFunction` with `#define xorFunction(a, b, c, d) ...`, then run `gcc -E -o main.i main.c`. You will get what you want in `main.i`.

Comment: gcc ? This is for Code Block right ? If so, I could try

Answer (score 2):

[Coccinelle ("semantic patches for C")](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/) is great for this kind of transformation:

> Coccinelle is a program matching and transformation engine which provides the language SmPL (Semantic Patch Language) for specifying desired matches and transformations in C code. Coccinelle was initially targeted towards performing collateral evolutions in Linux. Such evolutions comprise the changes that are needed in client code in response to evolutions in library APIs, and may include modifications such as renaming a function, adding a function argument whose value is somehow context-dependent, and reorganizing a data structure. Beyond collateral evolutions, Coccinelle is successfully used (by us and others) for finding and fixing bugs in systems code.

---

Another option is [Using Clang as a Library](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/index.html#using-clang-as-a-library). While in general it is more involved than writing a Coccinelle's semantic patch (even considering Clang Python bindings), in this case it should not be too hard. It has the advantage that you can parse C++ as well.

Comment: Hmmm; intriguing, though I note it requires OCaml, which makes it (a little) trickier to use than some other programs — I can't use it immediately, for example (I have to find/install OCaml, at minimum, first).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yeah, it has a dependency on OCaml and another library (Menhir from inria), indeed. However, it is available in several Linux distributions (e.g. in Ubuntu's `universe/devel`). For huge C code bases like the Linux kernel is a very nice tool to have.

Comment: Isn't there an other software that accomplishes the same job? Because the dependency on OCaml is a problem since I'm not very familiar with building libraries and so and plus, I'm under Windows which makes things even more complicated

Comment: @TomClabault: Added another option to the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have variables in regex.

`xorFunction \(\s*[^,]+,\s*[^,]+,\s*[^,]+,\s*[^\)]+\)` That would be regex for catching the xorFunction block, but you can't have variables in plain regex. You could try finding something else to do it, but I think it would be faster to just do it manually (copy arguments, use regex, replace)

Comment: Too bad. Imagine I have a thousand of call to xorFunction, everywhere in my code, that wouldn't be too practical to replace every one of them one by one hence my question. I'll use some external software then.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant, the external software is the best way to go :(, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a macro?  This might be sufficient:

```
#define xorFunction(a, b, c, d) for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) a[i] = b[i] ^ c[i]
```

A more nearly bullet-proof version would add some macro-verbiage:

```
#define xorFunction(a, b, c, d) do { for (int i = 0; i < (d); i++) (a)[i] = (b)[i] ^ (c)[i]; } while (0)
```

This would still run into problems if you have an expression that uses `i` as a variable in the call to `xorFunction()` — e.g. `xorFunction(…, &data[i], …)`.  Avoiding that is hard — using a macro to concatenate `i` with a line number or thereabouts might be a sufficiently robust alternative.

---

The more robust code might use:

```
#define CONCATENATE(v, n) v ## _ ## n
#define EVALUATE(v, n) CONCATENATE(v, n)
#define V(x) EVALUATE(x, __LINE__)

#define xorFunction(a, b, c, d) \
    do { \
        for (int V(i) = 0; V(i) < (d); V(i)++) \
            (a)[V(i)] = (b)[V(i)] ^ (c)[V(i)]; \
    } while (0)

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char input[16] = { ... };
    unsigned char mask[16] = { ... };
    unsigned char output[16];

    xorFunction(output, input, mask, 16);
    xorFunction(mask, output, input, 16);
    xorFunction(input, mask, output, 16);
    for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++)
        xorFunction(&ouput[i], &input[i], &mask[i], sizeof(mask)-i);

    return 0;
}
```

The output from the `cpp` I use is:

```
# 1 "xx.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "xx.c"
# 11 "xx.c"
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char input[16] = { ... };
    unsigned char mask[16] = { ... };
    unsigned char output[16];

    do { for (int i_17 = 0; i_17 < (16); i_17++) (output)[i_17] = (input)[i_17] ^ (mask)[i_17]; } while (0);
    do { for (int i_18 = 0; i_18 < (16); i_18++) (mask)[i_18] = (output)[i_18] ^ (input)[i_18]; } while (0);
    do { for (int i_19 = 0; i_19 < (16); i_19++) (input)[i_19] = (mask)[i_19] ^ (output)[i_19]; } while (0);
    for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++)
        do { for (int i_21 = 0; i_21 < (sizeof(mask)-i); i_21++) (&ouput[i])[i_21] = (&input[i])[i_21] ^ (&mask[i])[i_21]; } while (0);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that without the variable naming via the `V` macro, expressions such as `(&mask[i])[i]` would access data outside the bounds of the `mask` array if `i` reaches `8`, and doesn't access what's expected when `i` is less than `8` except when `i` is `0`.

Comment: That would be nice in the case I mentioned but the xorFunction was just an example. Also, I'd like the code to be replaced so it's clean but with a macro, that's just "code redirection"

Comment: I was afraid that you wanted that change to be permanent and a macro wasn't OK.  I'm not sure it's a good idea with the sample code.   A `static inline` function would be better.  However, if you're sure about the change, you need a system along the lines of the Coccinelle system suggested by [Acorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9305398/acorn) in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51181126/15168).  I know you've said that could be a problem.  Consider whether you can install an Ubuntu VM under your Windows machine, and then run Coccinelle on the code inside the VM.

Comment: That would be quite an effort for a straightforward text replacer. I'll search for a Windows compatible Coccinelle-like software.